# How to explode the below value from json data in laravel using php

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

From the below data I need to display the "Xeon E3 1230v3 Quad Core Server (21/09/2018 - 20/10/2018)" and how to explode the remaining data.

```
    Xeon E3 1230v3 Quad Core Server (21/09/2018 - 20/10/2018) Server Addons - OS: CentOs Server Addons - Database: Mysql Server Addons - Controlpanel: Plesk
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$chain = "Xeon E3 1230v3 Quad Core Server (21/09/2018 - 20/10/2018) Server Addons - OS: CentOs Server Addons - Database: Mysql Server Addons - Controlpanel: Plesk";

$regex = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\s\(\/]*\))/';
$data['regex'] = $regex;
$data['chain'] = $chain;

if(preg_match( $regex, $chain, $matches)){
    $remaining = str_replace($matches[0], "", $chain);
    $parts = explode(':', $remaining);
    $data['match'] = $matches[0];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($parts); $i++){
        $infos = explode('-', $parts[$i]);
        $data['properties']["{$infos[0]}"] = $infos[1];
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image]